# How can I use QuickTime to record two monitors?

Tags: mac, quicktime, screen-recorder

I'd like to record my pairing so I can watch it back for improvements.

Quicktime seems the easiest (and most trustworthy, given this is a work machine) solution to this but it only records on one of the two monitors at a time.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I was going to get all snippy & say "Why not just do it with Cmd/Shift/5?"… but you're right, either screen not both, even using area select. I know of no workaround, sorry. Wish you luck.